# react-native: Can't find variable Stylesheet after importing it

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm a bit perplexed on what should be a simple fix. I'm running a react-native project on version 0.27.2, and all of my `ios.js` files successfully import Stylesheet except one.

The import looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Cell,
  CustomCell,
  Section,
  TableView
} from 'react-native-tableview-simple';

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  container: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(20,25,30)',
    }
  }
);
```

The `Stylesheet.create({})` function is what ultimately causes the error `Can't find variable Stylesheet` to be thrown. However, I've declared styles the same way in every other file with the same imports, and those rendered the styles with no error.

The only thing that's different in this file is that multiple classes have been declared. I'm new to React, so I don't know if this could cause an issue. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: The second s in StyleSheet needs to be uppercase in the `const styles = Stylesheet.create`, should be `StyleSheet.create`

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Wow I can't believe I missed that thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mixed the case, you need to write

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
```

like you named it when you imported it.

Comment: I have written like this: const stylesDict = StyleSheet.create({
  description: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#656565',
    marginTop: 65,
  },
}); Still, same error. Can't find variable 'StyleSheet'. what should i try ?

Comment: You need to import StyleSheet from react native

Answer (score 0):

I just run into same issue and found out that types are in different module. If you have correct case(StyleSheet) and still doesn't work, it's very likely that you do not have type module installed. Just execute this line in cmd -

```
npm install --save @types/react-native
```

It should do the trick.